# Webpack build succeeded with missing immutable import?

Tags: typescript, webpack, immutable.js

I had a weird error today. I did update one module in our codebase (typescript) and omited importing of Immutable.

```
interface SomeTabProps {
  somePropHere: Immutable.Map<any, any>;
}
```

but without

```
import * as Immutable from 'immutable'
```

The problem was/is... My local build is passing without errors / warnings. But when my code was downloaded by my colleagues, their build failed - missing Immutable dependency.

Even now, when I comment out any import, my build will fail as it should. But if I comment out Immutable import, the build will simply pass without errors/warnings.

Did anyone saw this kind of issues? Not failing the build when it should fail?
What am I missing? There should be no auto global import of Immutable when using npm package, right?

Comment: Maybe your upstream repo is missing the dependency in the package.json while you have a copy in your node_modules?

Comment: I just checked the package.json and immutable is there ("immutable": "~3.8.1"). But still, good point, I didn't think about this possibility.